# Implementar gráfico de probabilidad condicionada para 3 variables

Tags: r

Dispongo de un archivo de datos con una variable dependiente y, y dos independientes x, z. A continuación un enlace a los datos:

[Datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxlsfvecbq04rsa/data.csv?dl=0)

Con ayuda de la comunidad, he implementado el siguiente código para graficar mediante un spineplot la relación entre y ~ x.

```
#Transforming values to categorical
y <- as.character(y)
y[y>=2]<-"high"
y[y < 2 & y >= 1]<-"medium"
y[y<1]<-"low"
#Sort plot by reorganizing levels in the graph
y <- factor(y, levels = c("low","medium","high"))
#x as a factor
x <- as.factor(x)
#Spineplot
library("RColorBrewer")
print.perc <- function(k, tbl, ndigits=2, str.pct="%", min=0.1, cex=0.8) {
  nx <- nrow(tbl)
  off <- 0.02
  xat <- c(0, cumsum(prop.table(margin.table(tbl, 1)) + off))
  posx <- (xat[1L:nx] + xat[2L:(nx + 1L)] - off)/2
  ptbl <- prop.table(tbl,1)
  lbl <- ifelse(ptbl[k,] >= min,
                paste(format(round(100*ptbl[k,], ndigits), nsmall=ndigits), str.pct, "\n",colnames(tbl), sep=""),
                "")
  text(posx[k], cumsum(ptbl[k,])-ptbl[k,]/2, lbl, cex=cex)
}
paleta <- brewer.pal(nlevels(y),"RdYlBu")
tbl <- spineplot(y ~ as.factor(x),
                 col=paleta, 
                 xlab = "x", 
                 ylab ="y", 
                 yaxlabels = "") 

for (k in 1:nrow(tbl)) print.perc(k, tbl, ndigits=2)
```

El resultado (utilizando los datos originales) es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría ahora elaborar un gráfico del mismo tipo pero incluyendo también la variable z. Es decir, se trataría de un gráfico que representase la probabilidad de que se de y, dadas cada una de las combinaciones entre x y z. Para ello, creo que debería tratarse de un gráfico spineplot o heatplot pero en 3D.

Muchas gracias de antemano por los comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hay algunas alternativas que podrías considerar. Depende, sobre todo, del contexto de interpretación del gráfico, es decir, ¿qué relaciones entre variables querés explorar? Entiendo que querés ver como se distribuye cada nivel de *y* en los diferentes niveles de *x* y *z*. Para esto podés hacer un spineplot por paneles, en el que cada barra es un nivel de *z* y en el interior se rellena por la proporción *y*. Como es una proporción el largo de cada barra es el mismo, es decir, no está expresando una magnitud relevante. Para agregar una tercera variable podés usar paneles, que reproducen el gráfico para cada nivel de *x* (en tu caso).

## Opción 1.

Te paso una implementación relativamente simple en `ggplot`. Es con los datos que subiste y se consideran a los missing de *x* como una categoría. En una misma cadena de funciones recodifica los datos, hace los conteos, calcula las proporciones, crea etiquetas para los valores superiores al 5% y produce el gráfico etiquetado.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)     # Para percent()
data %>% 
  mutate(y = case_when(y >= 2          ~ "high",
                       y  < 2 & y >= 1 ~ "medium",
                       y  < 1           ~ "low")) %>%              
  mutate_all(as.factor) %>%
  mutate(y = factor(y, levels = c("low", "medium", "high"))) %>%  
  group_by(y, x, z) %>%
  count() %>%
  group_by(x, z) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  mutate(etiqueta = ifelse(prop < 0.05, NA, percent(prop))) %>%  # Pasa a NA las etiquetas menores al 5%, sino formatea a porcentaje
  ggplot(aes(x = z, y = prop, fill = y)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    geom_text(aes(label = etiqueta), 
              position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), 
              size = 3) +
    facet_grid(x~.) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    labs(title = "Gráfico de Pyring", 
         caption = "Etiquetado condicional de las propociones superiores al 5%",
         y = NULL)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Para hacer etiquetado condicional en `ggplot()` la manera más directa es pasar a `NA` los valores que no queremos que impriman etiqueta usando `ifelse()`. `ggplot()` emitirá un `warning` avisando que hay casos perdidos, pero podemos ignorarlo con toda tranquilidad: está haciendo lo que le pedimos.

## Opción 2.

Considerando los datos que tenés también podrías hacer un heatmap. En ese caso estarías presentando la *n* para cada combinación de variables, no proporciones o probabilidades condicionales. Tampoco tiene la recodificación de y para dejar los datos lo más crudos posibles.

De todos modos creo te puede dar buena información sobre la distribución de tus variables.

```
data %>% 
  mutate_all(as.factor) %>% 
  group_by(y, x, z) %>%
  count() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = y, y = z, fill = n)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    facet_grid(x~.) + 
    theme_minimal() +  
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
    labs(title = "Gráfico de Pyring")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La opción de hacer un gráfico en 3D no me parece muy buena idea:

- Complica las comparaciones ya que las distancias de *x* y *y* no son homogéneas a lo largo de *z*.
- Es frecuente que quede información escondida. Ejp. Una barra más larga tapa a una barra corta detrás.
- En general son difíciles de leer.

Aún con los problemas que tienen creo que los gráficos por paneles son mejor alternativa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @mpaladino, he aprendido mucho de tu respuesta y me es muy útil.

Comment: Utilizando los códigos que has compartido, cuando corro el programa no obtengo los gráficos que dividen x en tres grupos (0,1,NA) sino los gráficos completos para todos los posibles niveles de x. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? Un saludo y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Por otra parte, estaría bien poder ordenar los niveles de y ("high", "medium", "low"). Estaba intentando esto: y <- factor(y, levels = c("low","medium","high")). ¿Sabes cómo implementar ese arreglo?

Comment: Finalmente, también he intentado implementar una etiqueta en el eje lateral derecho, pero parece que la función facet_grid no tiene esa opción. Sería interesnte poder hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Pyring. El gráfico que pego en la respuesta es exactamente el que obtengo con ese código y los datos descargados del DropBox. Tres paneles controlados por x, una columna por cada nivel de z rellenada por la proporción de y. Fijate que coincidan los nombres exactamente.

Comment: Edité la respuesta para reordenar y. Tu idea era la correcta, sólo que usando tubería tenés que usar `mutate()` para hacer cambios en una columna. De este modo podés hacer todo en una misma cadena y no es necesario asignar con `<-`. Son estilos, yo estoy acostrumbrado a usar este.

Comment: Sobre las etiquetas, no entiendo bien que es lo que querrías lograr. ¿Poner un título a las etiquetas de panel (0, 1, NA)? ¿Cambiar esos nombres para que digan otra cosa (p. ej. Grupo Tratamiento, Grupo Control, etc.)? Si es esto último la mejor opción es directamente recodificar el factor y cambiar los nombres antes de graficar. Si es lo primero es posible, pero bastante complicado. En https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353287/how-do-you-add-a-general-label-to-facets-in-ggplot2? hay una opción con `gtable` y `grid`.

Comment: Hola @mpaladino. He conseguido que todo funcione más o menos bien y he implementado algunos cambios para adaptarlo a mis datos. Gracias. Es la primera vez que trabajo con operadores del tipo  %>%, y me está costando aplicar otras funcionalidades. Por ejemplo, tengo varios datframes diferentes y querría poder guardar los gráficos para luego plotearlos juntos. Algo así: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2 . En cualquier caso, quizá sea mejor abrir una pregunta nueva para este asunto.

Comment: Hola @mpaladino. ¿Podría implementarse en el código que has compartido (en el primero, el de las probabilidades condicionadas), la posibilidad de "no" imprimir valores inferiores a 5%?

Comment: Actualicé las respuesta. La clave es pasar a `NA` los valores que no querés que impriman etiqueta. Sirve para este caso y para cualquier otro el que quieras hacer etiquetado condicional en `ggplot()`. **Atención:** es importante pasar a `NA` sólo las etiquetas y no el dato que querés graficar, de lo contrario desaparecen también los objetos geométricos.

Comment: Gracias. No sé si me pierdo algo. Tengo este error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: could not find function "percent".

Comment: falta cargar la librería `scales`, que importa la función `percent`, ahora lo edito